# How to select default option in rails 4 select_tag with multiple true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to select default string when no option is selected. I tried the following but its not working

```
<%=select_tag "users", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "name",""),prompt: "select user",:multiple => true%>
```

I am not getting any selected value, how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1f5b58c079cc0ae3ee217eb3f1b4c5b2273a16e1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L148) code. As you can see prompt option doesn't have ability to specify `selected` attribute.

So, in your case you can add this attribute manually:

```
option_tags = options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "name")
option_tags = content_tag(:option, "select user", value: '', selected: '').safe_concat(option_tags)

select_tag "users", option_tags, :multiple => true
```